# Creating a line separated gradient bar in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, gradient

I am trying to create something similar to this in Tikz:

[image]

I have been looking at using the \shadedraw macro, but have not found a way to create the color spectrum.  It seems possible if I stack multiple gradient-shaded rectangles on top of each other, but I would rather not use such a lengthy and ugly solution.  Is there a way to recreate this PH-scale image in Tikz, ideally using few rectangles?  (Note: the number labels are not necessary, as they will be replaced with horizontal lines anyway.)

Comment: Something very similar to this have been presented by [Luigi](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13482/luigi) in the [italian forum](http://www.guitex.org/home/it/forum/5-tex-e-latex/84571-spettro-elettromagnetico-con-tikz?limit=15&start=15#84631).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\foreach` is your friend!

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\mycolorbar}[3]% height,width,colors
{   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x [count=\c] in {#3}{ \xdef\numcolo{\c}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pieceheight}{#1/(\numcolo-1)}
        \xdef\lowcolo{}
        \foreach \x [count=\c] in {#3}
        {   \ifthenelse{\c = 1}
            {}
            {   \fill[bottom color=\lowcolo,top color=\x] (0,{(\c-2)*\pieceheight}) rectangle (#2,{(\c-1)*\pieceheight});
            }
            \xdef\lowcolo{\x}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\mycolorbar{10}{1}{red,orange,yellow,green,cyan,blue,violet,red}
\mycolorbar{10}{1}{black,blue,white,red,black,yellow,white,green,black}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

### Edit 1:

Now with labels. You might have a look at the source of the *pgfplots* manual, in the section *color maps* you can find quite a few examples.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\mycolorbar}[6]% height,width,colors,label min,label max,label step
{   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x [count=\c] in {#3}{ \xdef\numcolo{\c}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pieceheight}{#1/(\numcolo-1)}
        \xdef\lowcolo{}
        \foreach \x [count=\c] in {#3}
        {   \ifthenelse{\c = 1}
            {}
            {   \fill[bottom color=\lowcolo,top color=\x] (0,{(\c-2)*\pieceheight}) rectangle (#2,{(\c-1)*\pieceheight});
            }
            \xdef\lowcolo{\x}
        }
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (#2,#1);
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondlabel}{#4+#6}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastlabel}{#5+0.01}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2}
        \foreach \x in {#4,\secondlabel,...,\lastlabel}
        { \draw (#2,{(\x-#4)/(#5-#4)*#1}) -- ++ (0.05,0) node[right] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\x}};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\mycolorbar{10}{1}{red,orange,yellow,green,cyan,blue,violet,magenta,red}{-0.4}{0.4}{0.1}
\mycolorbar{10}{1}{black,blue,white,red,black,yellow,white,green,black}{-13}{11}{2}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have these colour bars in horizontal format, without numbers and in grey colours, sorted from black to white?

Answer (score 1):

I propose this direct way of producing the colors (one for each step of the loop).  Changing the colors' definition, we may obtain different gradients.
[image]

The code defines a 100 mm long bar.  So the height of each rectangle in the bar is given by `100/\N`, where `\N` is a parameter representing the number of steps.

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\tikzmath{
  int \N, \steps;
  real \hue, \dy;
  \N = 180;
  \dy = 100/\N;
  \intervals = 8;  % for the labels
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \hue using \i/\N] in {0, 1, ..., \N}{%
    \xdefinecolor{tmp}{hsb}{\hue, 1, 1}
    \filldraw[tmp, very thin] (0, \i*\dy mm) rectangle ++(20mm, \dy mm);
  }

  \path (25 mm, 0) -- ++(0, 100 mm)
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \dy using (\i-4)*.1] in {0, ..., \intervals}{%
    node[pos={\i/\intervals}] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\dy}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `\path` command writes down the gradations; it is not necessary for the generation of the gradient bar.