# Tikz Pgfplot-Create user defined colorbar

Tags: pgfplots, color

I want to create only colorbar in Latex. Earlier I have used to Gnuplot to plot heatmaps along with colorbox(yeah, They are called colorbox in Gnuplot). 
The user defined colorbox in Gnuplot plot is given as follows

```
set colorbox
set palette defined ( 0 '#000090',\
                      1 '#000fff',\
                      2 '#0090ff',\
                      3 '#0fffee',\
                      4 '#ffee00',\
                      5 '#ff7000',\
                      6 '#ee0000',\
                      7 '#7f0000')
set cbrange [25:900]
show colorbox
```

How do I generate an equivalent colorbar in Latex?

The colorbox from Gnuplot looks like this
[image]

Comment: Does [this anwer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141448/creating-a-line-separated-gradient-bar-in-tikz/141458#141458) help?