# How to draw a pH scale in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemistry

I am trying to display a pH scale in LaTeX but Im having trouble figuring it out. All the googling I have been able to do just brings up the pH levels of Latex the material. Can someone offer some advice/resources?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The short answer is that this is possible *but* I have to warn you that questions of the form "Please draw this for me" that show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A quick search on TeX.SX for drawing functions (with tikz or pstricks) will give you an idea of where to start. At the very least tell us what this scale should look like.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141448/creating-a-line-separated-gradient-bar-in-tikz could be a starting point?

Comment: With no specifications, this also could be a start point: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
\hfil 0 & \hfil 7 & \hfil 14 \\
\cellcolor{red} & \cellcolor{green} & \cellcolor{blue}\\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}`

Comment: Unfortunatly I was not able to get any of these examples working, I do not know why but I eventually went with placing an image of the pH Scale in the document using `\includegraphics`

Comment: Did you put \usepackage{tikz} in your preamble?

Answer (score 7):

Update: pH scale with colors in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH_indicator. (Paul Gaborit suggested)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.6,font=\sffamily]
\fill[left color=red,right color=orange]
(0,0) rectangle (3,1);
\fill[left color=orange,right color=green]
(3,0) rectangle (7.5,1);
\fill[left color=green,right color=blue]
(7.5,0) rectangle (12,1);
\fill[left color=blue,right color=violet]
(12,0) rectangle (15,1);
\draw[white] (0,0) grid (15,1);

\foreach \i in {0,...,14}
\path (\i+.5,0) node[below]{\i};
\path 
(0,1) node[above right]{Acidic}
(7.5,1) node[above]{Neutral}
(15,1) node[above left]{Alkaline};
\path (current bounding box.south) node[below=2mm,scale=1.5]{\bfseries pH scale};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

---

I choose red for Axidic, violet for Neutral, and cyan for Alkaline. Tell me if you have a better choice of colors for pH scale.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.6,font=\sffamily]
\fill[left color=red,middle color=violet,right color=cyan] (0,0) rectangle (15,1);
\draw[white] (0,0) grid (15,1);
\foreach \i in {0,...,14} \path (\i+.5,0) node[below]{\i};
\path 
(0,1) node[above right]{Acidic}
(7.5,1) node[above]{Neutral}
(15,1) node[above left]{Alkaline};
\path (current bounding box.south) node[below=2mm,scale=2]{\bfseries pH scale};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Suggestion for the colors : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_indicator

Comment: @N.F.Taussig my bad! I correct now.