# Colored bar with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to reproduce with tikz a picture like the following:

[image]

How would I do that?

Comment: In your many questions you almost never post a MWE. In my opinion, this is not nice to the community.

Comment: This may give you a suggestion https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528103/how-to-draw-a-ph-scale-in-latex/528116#528116

Comment: @BlackMild I used your proposal to mark a potential duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `colorbar`s of pgfplot for that. This colorbar can be found on p. 199 of the pgfplots manual v1.16.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\large\bfseries]
\begin{scope}
\clip(-0.1,-0.81) rectangle (6.1,0.01);
\pgfplotscolorbardrawstandalone[
    colormap={hot}{
        samples of colormap=(4)
    },
    colorbar horizontal,
    colormap access=map,
]
\end{scope}
\path (6.25,0) node[above right] {position 1} (0,0) node[above] {position 2}
(3,-1) node[below] {title};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do not want to clip, you can do

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\large\bfseries]
\pgfplotscolorbardrawstandalone[
    colormap={hot}{
        samples of colormap=(3)
    },
    colorbar horizontal,
    colormap access=map,
    xticklabel style={opacity=0,overlay}
]
\path (6.25,0) node[above right] {position 1} (0,0) node[above] {position 2}
(3,-1) node[below] {title};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which leads to the same result.

Comment: +1: Are the clip parameters trial and error or is there a logic behind them?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I added an equivalent version without `\clip`.